# Can I include custom attributes on auto-generated WCF classes?

Tags: .net, wcf, wsdl

I have a WSDL-fisrt approach to generating Web Services. Basically, this means, I have a hand-crafted version of how I want my service to look, and then generate the WCF service by using `svcutil`.

This WSDL contains a lot of useful information such as minOccurs, maxOccurs, restrictions (regexp), etc. However, this information is completely lost when I get my auto-generated classes.

Is there any way I can capture this information in annotations (whether "standard" .net provided, or custom) on the properties so that I can perform validation on the objects after they've been deserialized?

Note: I know you can perform validation on the incoming stream through service behaviors and message inspectors, but I'm looking for a solution where I can perform validation on the generated code without having to write complex validation rules that I've already defined elsewhere. (i.e., I don't want duplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can translate any information from the WSDL into code, but not necessarily using svcutil.  If you're running up against the limitations of what svcutil supports, you might want to consider another code generation mechanism, such as T4 templates.

Comment: By taking the T4 approach, would I actually need to traverse my entire wsdl/xsds in order to get these attributes? Do you know of any example templates that do something of the sort?

Comment: With a T4 approach, you would need to re-implement the entire WSDL to code generation so, yes, you would need to traverse the entire WSDL source.  For sample templates, try http://www.google.com/search?q=t4+wsdl.

Answer (score 1):

By making the "minOccurs, maxOccurs, restrictions (regexp), etc" references in your question, it sounds like you're mainly concerned with serializing the wsdl:types element contents as data contract classes while maintaining the XSD metadata. If this is the case then you can try the [XSD.EXE command line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to generate the classes from the extracted XSDs from WSDL types. I don't know how the XSD utility enforces the XSD metadata/restrictions (if at all) but it will give you more control of the class structure than the DataContractSerializer based classes generated by SvcUtil.

UPDATE:
The .NET XmlSerializer does support marking classes with [minOccurs and other attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds0b35c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) but that functionality was part of the original ASMX based web services. I believe the XmlSerializer will still respect these attributes even though they were intended for ASMX use (YMMV).

Comment: However, as of version 4 of the framework, he XmlSerializer (as per your link) is now marked as a "Legacy techonolgy", and I wouldn't like to base new code on something that's been marked as deprecated.

Comment: That's understandable but this is the only Microsoft provided tooling that's available to do what you want. Remember, WCF provides a messaging **abstraction** of which soap (as defined by WSDL) is an implementation detail. If you want to work at the XSD level then XmlSerializer gives you that capability. That doesn't mean you have to abandon WCF, you just need to control the classes that represent service data contracts. [WCF fully supports using XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx) based classes.