# dotnet-svcutil generation from file without namespace

Tags: .net, wcf

Have 2 issue. Maybe someone can help me. I am using mac os with .net5 and [dotnet-svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x) Version 2.0.2. I didn't find any reference anywhere.:

1. When i generate reference from xml file generated classes don't use any namespace. How can i configure it?

This was resolved using arguments --namespace

```
dotnet-svcutil SourceServices/UsersWebPortal.wsdl --outputDir ServicesSvcUtil/ServiceUsersWebPortal --sync --namespace "*,ServiceUsersWebPortal"
```

2. Generated annotation uses order of fields, instead i want to use attribute name. Can i change it.

For example

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
    public int SUCID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sUCIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sUCIDField = value;
        }
    }
```

and i want

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SUCID")]
    public int SUCID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sUCIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sUCIDField = value;
        }
    }
```

My xml wsdl looks like

```
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments"
                    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:simpleType name="SUCAllDay">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="M"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:complexType name="SUCAppointments">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCID" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EmployeeCode" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCNameEmpl" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCTypeAppoint" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCDescription" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUC_H_Enjoyed" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCHolidays" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCStart" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCEnd" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCStatusAppoint" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUC_Status_Description" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUC_Dept" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUC_Appo_Qty" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCText" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAllDay" type="tns:SUCAllDay"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCEmployeeRead" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="SUCAppointments_List">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SUCAppointments" type="tns:SUCAppointments"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleType name="SUCAppointments_Fields">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCID"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="EmployeeCode"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCNameEmpl"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCTypeAppoint"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCDescription"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUC_H_Enjoyed"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCHolidays"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCStart"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCEnd"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCStatusAppoint"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUC_Status_Description"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUC_Dept"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUC_Appo_Qty"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCText"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCAllDay"/>
                    <xsd:enumeration value="SUCEmployeeRead"/>
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:complexType name="SUCAppointments_Filter">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field" type="tns:SUCAppointments_Fields"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Criteria" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:element name="Read">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCID" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Read_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments" type="tns:SUCAppointments"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ReadByRecId">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="recId" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ReadByRecId_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments" type="tns:SUCAppointments"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ReadMultiple">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="filter"
                                     type="tns:SUCAppointments_Filter"/>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="bookmarkKey" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="setSize" type="xsd:int"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ReadMultiple_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ReadMultiple_Result"
                                     type="tns:SUCAppointments_List"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="IsUpdated">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="IsUpdated_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IsUpdated_Result" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="GetRecIdFromKey">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="GetRecIdFromKey_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GetRecIdFromKey_Result" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Create">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments" type="tns:SUCAppointments"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Create_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments" type="tns:SUCAppointments"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="CreateMultiple">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments_List"
                                     type="tns:SUCAppointments_List"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="CreateMultiple_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments_List"
                                     type="tns:SUCAppointments_List"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Update">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments" type="tns:SUCAppointments"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Update_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments" type="tns:SUCAppointments"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="UpdateMultiple">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments_List"
                                     type="tns:SUCAppointments_List"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="UpdateMultiple_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="SUCAppointments_List"
                                     type="tns:SUCAppointments_List"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Delete">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="xsd:string"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="Delete_Result">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Delete_Result" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="Read">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Read"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Read_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Read_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ReadByRecId">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:ReadByRecId"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ReadByRecId_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:ReadByRecId_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ReadMultiple">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:ReadMultiple"/>
    </message>
    <message name="ReadMultiple_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:ReadMultiple_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="IsUpdated">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:IsUpdated"/>
    </message>
    <message name="IsUpdated_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:IsUpdated_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetRecIdFromKey">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetRecIdFromKey"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetRecIdFromKey_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:GetRecIdFromKey_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Create">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Create"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Create_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Create_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="CreateMultiple">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateMultiple"/>
    </message>
    <message name="CreateMultiple_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateMultiple_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Update">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Update"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Update_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Update_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="UpdateMultiple">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateMultiple"/>
    </message>
    <message name="UpdateMultiple_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:UpdateMultiple_Result"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Delete">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Delete"/>
    </message>
    <message name="Delete_Result">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:Delete_Result"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="SUCAppointments_Port">
        <operation name="Read">
            <input name="Read" message="tns:Read"/>
            <output name="Read_Result" message="tns:Read_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="ReadByRecId">
            <input name="ReadByRecId" message="tns:ReadByRecId"/>
            <output name="ReadByRecId_Result" message="tns:ReadByRecId_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="ReadMultiple">
            <input name="ReadMultiple" message="tns:ReadMultiple"/>
            <output name="ReadMultiple_Result" message="tns:ReadMultiple_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="IsUpdated">
            <input name="IsUpdated" message="tns:IsUpdated"/>
            <output name="IsUpdated_Result" message="tns:IsUpdated_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetRecIdFromKey">
            <input name="GetRecIdFromKey" message="tns:GetRecIdFromKey"/>
            <output name="GetRecIdFromKey_Result" message="tns:GetRecIdFromKey_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Create">
            <input name="Create" message="tns:Create"/>
            <output name="Create_Result" message="tns:Create_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="CreateMultiple">
            <input name="CreateMultiple" message="tns:CreateMultiple"/>
            <output name="CreateMultiple_Result" message="tns:CreateMultiple_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Update">
            <input name="Update" message="tns:Update"/>
            <output name="Update_Result" message="tns:Update_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="UpdateMultiple">
            <input name="UpdateMultiple" message="tns:UpdateMultiple"/>
            <output name="UpdateMultiple_Result" message="tns:UpdateMultiple_Result"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Delete">
            <input name="Delete" message="tns:Delete"/>
            <output name="Delete_Result" message="tns:Delete_Result"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SUCAppointments_Binding" type="tns:SUCAppointments_Port">
        <binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        <operation name="Read">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:Read" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="Read">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Read_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="ReadByRecId">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:ReadByRecId" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="ReadByRecId">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="ReadByRecId_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="ReadMultiple">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:ReadMultiple" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="ReadMultiple">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="ReadMultiple_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="IsUpdated">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:IsUpdated" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="IsUpdated">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="IsUpdated_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="GetRecIdFromKey">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:GetRecIdFromKey" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="GetRecIdFromKey">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="GetRecIdFromKey_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Create">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:Create" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="Create">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Create_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="CreateMultiple">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:CreateMultiple" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="CreateMultiple">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="CreateMultiple_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Update">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:Update" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="Update">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Update_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="UpdateMultiple">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:UpdateMultiple" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="UpdateMultiple">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="UpdateMultiple_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="Delete">
            <operation soapAction="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/sucappointments:Delete" style="document"
                       xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            <input name="Delete">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="Delete_Result">
                <body use="literal" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SUCAppointments_Service">
        <port name="SUCAppointments_Port" binding="tns:SUCAppointments_Binding">
            <address
                    location="http://localhost/WS/DEMO/Page/SUCAppointments"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: You can check out this post for help : [Can I include custom attributes on auto-generated WCF classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613951/can-i-include-custom-attributes-on-auto-generated-wcf-classes)

Comment: Updated questions, first one was resolved.